# AirDrop: Bluetooth or Wi-Fi?

Tags: ios, wifi, bluetooth, airdrop

How does AirDrop work? I thought it is just Bluetooth, but I am starting to doubt that now.

Whenever I turn AirDrop on, my Wi-Fi and Bluetooth are automatically turned on. If I turn the Wi-Fi off, and try to AirDrop, *sometimes* it works, but sometimes it doesn't. It *never* works if I turn the Bluetooth off instead.

So... Why does this happen? How does AirDrop work?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

AirDrop uses Bluetooth to create a peer-to-peer Wi-Fi network between the devices.

Each device creates a firewall around the connection and files are sent encrypted, which actually makes it safer than transferring via email. AirDrop will automatically detect nearby supported devices, and the devices only need to be close enough to establish a good Wi-Fi connection, making it possible to share files across several rooms.

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-airdrop-how-does-it-work-1994512

Comment: After reading this answer, I am more confused than before. What does it even mean, to "use Bluetooth to create a Wi-Fi network"? Is it Bluetooth or is it Wi-Fi? Why do you need a "good Wi-Fi connection", if it the protocol is based on Bluetooth?

Answer (score 11):

### The more detailed, and technical version of @Buscar웃's answer, from [Apples iOS Security Guide (2018) Page 40](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf), bolded by me:

> iOS devices that support AirDrop use **Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) and
>   Apple-created peer-to-peer Wi-Fi technology** to send files and
>   information to nearby devices, including AirDrop-capable Mac computers
>   running OS X 10.11 or later. The **Wi-Fi radio** is used to communicate
>   directly between devices **without using any Internet connection or
>   Wi-Fi Access Point.**   When a user enables AirDrop, a **2048-bit RSA
>   identity** is stored on the device. Additionally, **an AirDrop identity
>   hash is created based on the email addresses and phone numbers
>   associated with the user’s Apple ID.**
>
> When a user chooses AirDrop as the method for sharing an item, the
>   device emits an **AirDrop signal over Bluetooth Low Energy**. Other
>   devices **that are awake, in close proximity, and have AirDrop turned on**
>   detect the signal and respond with a shortened version of their
>   owner’s identity hash.
>
> **AirDrop is set to share with Contacts Only by default**. Users can also
>   choose to use AirDrop to share with everyone, or turn off the feature
>   entirely. In Contacts Only mode, the received identity hashes are
>   compared with hashes of people in the initiator’s Contacts app. If a
>   match is found, **the sending device creates a peer-to-peer Wi-Fi
>   network and advertises an AirDrop connection using Bonjour**. Using this
>   connection, the **receiving devices send their full identity hashes to
>   the initiator**. If the full hash still matches Contacts, the
>   recipient’s first name and photo (if present in Contacts) are
>   displayed in the AirDrop share sheet.
>
> When using AirDrop, the sending user selects who they want to share
>   with. The sending device initiates an **encrypted (TLS) connection with
>   the receiving device, which exchanges their iCloud identity
>   certificates**. The identity in the certificates is verified against
>   each user’s Contacts app. Then the receiving user is **asked to accept
>   the incoming transfer from the identified person or device**. If
>   multiple recipients have been selected, **this process is repeated for
>   each destination.**
>
> In the Everyone mode, the same process is used but if a match in
>   Contacts isn’t found, the receiving devices are shown in the AirDrop
>   send sheet with a silhouette with the device’s name, as defined in
>   Settings > General > About > Name.
>
> **Organizations can restrict the use of AirDrop** for devices or apps
>   being managed by using an **MDM solution.**

Comment: Wow this is really helpful. Thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 8):

Bluetooth LE is used for local discovery of other Airdroppers and WiFi direct is used for transmitting anything of meaningful size since it has a MUCH faster xfer rate.

[And here's a longer version of that explanation](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2231456&seqNum=2).

Answer (score 3):

[There's a way to use Airdrop without Wi-fi connection](http://itedstore.blogspot.com/2015/01/still-can-use-airdrop-even-though-your.html)

There's a way to bring back the "Airdrop" to Finder again even that you just in Ethernet/LAN connection. Simply run the command terminal below:

```
defaults write com.apple.NetworkBrowser BrowseAllInterfaces 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It uses Bluetooth to locate the Air Drop enabled device & create device to device Wi-Fi link (Wi-Fi Direct) to transfer files

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, AirDrop creates a temporary point-to-point Wi-Fi connection between the two devices, which is why Wi-Fi must be enabled to use it.

But, and this is an important point, your computer does not need to be *connected* to any Wi-Fi access point.

In my case, my Mac is connected to my home network via Ethernet.  I have the Wi-Fi interface enabled, but I've deliberately disconnected it from all access points.  To do this:

- In the Network settings, uncheck "Automatically join this network", so it won't reconnect after a restart.
- You might also want to uncheck "Ask to join Personal Hotspots"
- If you are connected to a network, option-click the Wi-Fi icon in the menu bar and then click "Disconnect from *your_SSID*" to disconnect.

At this point, Wi-Fi is on, but it is not connected to any access point and will therefore not be used for LAN communication.  But the Mac will be able to use it to create the point-to-point connection used by AirDrop.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned AirDrop uses both Bluetooth and Wi-Fi but it has now been [reverse engineered](https://www.usenix.org/conference/usenixsecurity19/presentation/stute) and is available in an open source implementation, [OpenDrop](https://github.com/seemoo-lab/opendrop), as part of the [Open Wireless Link Project](https://owlink.org/code/).