# Copy a movie between iPhones

Tags: iphone, ios

Seems like an idiot question, but I completely failed to copy a movie from one iPhone to another.

1. We tried coupling with bluetooth, failed to send files.
2. Enabling internet sharing (which worked) but failed to send files through Airdrop.

I understand that if we were connected to a WIFI network Airdrop would probably have worked. But we were on a trip travelling in a car, so there was no WIFI availability.

Remembering sharing photos over BT with friends ages ago using old push-button cell phones is seems crazy that we could not find out how to do it.

Can this be done? (iOS 9.3, iPhone 6 + SE)

Comment: Apparently AirDrop should work without you both being connected to the same Wi-Fi: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146644/airdrop-bluetooth-or-wifi

Comment: Thanks. We tried using airdrop symbols in the Photos app (Share-menu) in various ways but no luck. How is it supposed to work? The connection never shows up in the other iPhone...

Comment: Did you have AirDrop setup for 'Everyone', 'Contacts Only', or 'Off'?  If 'Contacts Only' you need to make sure you're each in the others Contacts app.

Comment: @fbara Where do I change the "AirDrop setup"?

Comment: I can't add a screenshot from the computer I'm at.  If you're on the Home screen and swipe up from the bottom, you'll see a bunch of icons.  Toward the bottom 1/3rd of the sheet you'll see the AirDrop icon with the words I indicated above.  This allows you to limit the people with whom you can share.  You both should have the same setting to ensure you can see each other.

Comment: @fbara Sorry for late reply, yes it works, please add the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the *Home* screen (or on any screen with something you want to share), swipe up from the bottom.  You should see a bunch of icons. Toward the bottom 1/3rd of the sheet you'll see the `AirDrop` icon.  Tap the `AirDrop` icon and 3 choices will slide-up from the bottom:

- **Everyone**
- **Contacts Only**
- **Off**

[image]

These choices allow you to limit the people with whom you can share. You both should have the same setting to ensure you can see each other.